# ASPX - Reading master page element returns null

Tags: asp.net

I have an anchor link in the master page and trying to assign its `href` in code behind, but the element is `null`.

**Default.master**

```
<body>
   <header>
      <asp:Hyperlink ID="ancLogout" runat="Server" Text="Logout" />
   </header>
</body>
```

**Default.master.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (ancLogout != null)
    {
      ancLogout.NavigateUrl = String.Format("{0}?logout=1", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri); 
    }
}
```

The `ancLogout` is always null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have just tried your exact code and theres no issues for me? ... maybe a lower case 'S' on server but shouldn't matter

Comment: `Server` was the issue. Changing it to `server` worked for me. Thank you.